# $2$-Normed Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Someone suggested today that $2$-normed spaces are actually equivalent to normed spaces. Can anyone who's familiar with the topic provide a counterexample? (I can't access Gähler's original paper introducing the notion, and hence have no way of telling whether the answer has already been provided there.)

[Recall: (Gähler, 1963) If $X$ is a vector space over $F$ (either the real or the complex field), then a real-valued, non-negative function $N$ on $X^2$ is said to be a $2$-norm on $X$ iff the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $N(x,\ y)=0$ iff $x,\ y$ are linearly dependent vectors in $X$;
2. $N(x,\ y)=N(y,\ x)$ for every $x,\ y \in X$;
3. $N(\lambda x,\ y)=|\lambda|N(x,\ y)$ for every $\lambda \in F$ and for every $x,\ y \in X$;
4. $N(x+y,\ z) \le N(x,\ z)+N(y,\ z)$ for all $x,\ y,\ z \in X$.]

Clarification: [Gähler](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=T7FMg6nT9KIC&lpg=PA219&ots=fSwZP9PFdY&dq=Geometry%20of%20Linear%202-Normed%20Spaces&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=Geometry%20of%20Linear%202-Normed%20Spaces&f=false) shows that linear $2$-normed spaces are normable and uniformizable provided the dimension of the space is greater than one. He also proves that if the space is a linear normed space, then it's possible to define a 2-norm on it. However, *the converse is not true.* This is the part I want the evidence of, preferably from the link to his original paper given below.

Edit: I finally got hold of the relevant paper by [Gähler](http://www.mediafire.com/view/5s3x76daiodtkd7/Mathematische_Nachrichten_Volume_28_issue_1-2_1964_%5Bdoi_10.1002/mana.19640280102%5D_Siegfried_G%C3%A4hler_--_Lineare_2-normierte_R%C3%A4ume.pdf), but it's in German. Since my understanding of that particular language is limited to mere recognition of a few words, I would be grateful if someone helped me out by reading it and translating the answer therein.

P. S.: Please excuse my second link not rendering properly--I am too inexperienced, evidently. Somehow, the angular brackets don't seem to be working.

Comment: Let $x\in X$ be an arbitrary nonzero vector, and let $Y$ be an arbitrary complementary subspace of $\ {\rm span}(x)$. Then, for $v\in Y$, we can define
$$\|v\|\ :=\ N(v, x)\,,$$
which *is a norm* on $Y$ by conditions 1., 3., 4.
I'm not sure if we can bunch these together for a norm on the whole space $X$.

Comment: @Berci: With your choice of $x$, $\|x \|=0$ by 1. while $x \neq 0$. Taking $x=0$ seems to be better, no?

Comment: If "someone" suggested it, maybe you should ask that person.

Comment: @GEdgar: Looking back, I sure wish I could've asked him, but he's a professor at a different university than where I'm a student at. A friend of mine attended a seminar where he gave a lecture, and in their conversations later, this topic turned up.

Comment: @12455421 It seems to me that Gähler shows that every 2-normed linear space of dimension $\neq 1$ is a locally convex topological vector space and as such a space uniformizable but he gives  an example for a $2$-normed linear space that is not normable, I tried to translate the relevant part, the proof seems quite technical

Comment: just realized You asked this 4 years ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

Gähler defines for $i=(i_1,i_2)\in I=(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$ the function $e_i=e_{(i_1,i_2)}\in (-\infty,\infty)^{I}$ to be one for $j=i$ and zero otherwise. He defines the space $L$ to be the linear hull of these functions and defines

$$||e_i,e_j||=0\text{ if } i=j,\sup\{i_2,j_2\}\text{ if }i_1=j_1\text{ and }i_2\neq j_2,1\text{ if }i_1\neq j_1.$$
Two elements of $L$ say $a,b$ can be written $a=\sum_{j\in I'}\alpha_je_j$ and $b=\sum_{j\in I'}\beta_je_j$ by using the same finite subset $I'\subset I$. He defines $$||a,b||=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j\in I'}|\alpha_i\beta_j-\alpha_j\beta_i|||e_i,e_j||$$ and states that this is a $2$-norm on $L$ and that $L$ is equipped with a topology generated by $\sigma(a,b,c)=||b-a,c-a||$. He then proves that $L$ is not metrizable and thus not normable.